# ngControl with ngFor in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-forms

**Q1.** Is it possible to have one Control 
ie:

```
ValidNumber = new Control('', CustomValidators.number({min:1, max:10}))
```

to validate all similar type of `input` fields in the template ?

**Q2.** Can these fields be generated by `ngFor` ?

---

**FailedMethod 1:** Validation works but values are coupled.

```
<input [ngFormControl]="ValidNumber" name="num1" type="number"/>
<input [ngFormControl]="ValidNumber" name="num2" type="number"/>
```

**FailedMethod 2:** With formBuilder it's same as above.

```
<form [ngFormModel]="formBuiltWithFormBuilder">
  <input ngControl="ValidNumber" name="num1" type="number"/>
  <input ngControl="ValidNumber" name="num2" type="number"/>
</from>
```

---

**Objective Clarification:**

- I'm trying to validate form fields that might be generated with ngFor
  and require similar validation.
- Without defining similar Controls repeatedly elsewhere.
- Values I can extract with any other method like `#form="ngForm"` or `ngModel`, all I want from `ngControl` is Validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also generate the controls then there is no problem.

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
...
<input *ngFor="let c in controls" [ngFormControl]="c" name="c.name" type="number"/>
...
`
})
class MyComponent {
  // initialization with `['a', 'b', 'c']` just for demo purposes
  // these values probably come from outside - hence @Input()
  @Input() controlNames:string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 

  controls: Control[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.controlNames.forEach(
        v => this.controls.push(
            new Control('', CustomValidators.number{min:1, max:10})
        )
    );
  }
}
```

(code not tested)

`controls` needs to be updated when `controlNames` changes. `ngOnInit()` runs only once.

Comment: It's eye pleasing, I also coded something like this `mentally` but I'm also trying to not loop elsewhere other than template's ngFor, that's where the real challenge lies, I think.

Comment: You can move the code `ValidNumber = new Control('', CustomValidators.number({min:1, max:10}))` into a directive, then you can use theh `*ngFor` iteration and don't need another one in your code.

Comment: For current version of Angular2 (2.2.x), Control should be FormControl and [ngFormControl] should be [formControl]