# Angular2 form ControlGroup who hold an undefined number of Control

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-template

How to manage with Angular2 a form who hold an undefined number of field ?

In my case, I need to create a from where user can add and delete some block of fileds. It's like an address book where user can add one or ten address. And each address had a some fields like street, street number and so on.

My look like this :

```
let address = fb.group({
        street: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        streetNumber fb.control(null, Validators.required)
    });

this.userForm = fb.group({
        name: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        firstName: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        address: fb.group({
            1: address
            })
        });
```

I really don't know how to manage this in the template.

I've try to write some thing like that in the template, but obviously, it doesn't work...

```
<form [ngFormModel]="userForm">
<input type="text" ngControl="name" #name="ngForm"/>
<input type="text" ngControl="firstName" #firstName="ngForm"/>

<div *ngFor="#address of userForm.controls['address'].controls">
    <input type="text" ngControl="street" #street="ngForm"/>
    <input type="text" ngControl="streetNumber" #streetNumber="ngForm"/>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I've made a Plunker for a better explanation http://plnkr.co/edit/ffYe1479WnxYOQrbxwLF?p=preview

Comment: What does "obviously doesn't work mean"?

Comment: The template I've wrote don't do the job, because it's not the right way to write it. Angular raise error because he don't find the control 'street' in the control group 'userForm'.

Comment: Doesn't look like you need `#street="ngForm"`. What if you remove it?

Comment: #street="ngForm" is useful for me because I use it in an component to show some errors to the user.

I think the issue come from ngControl="street", because 'street' isn't defined in 'userForm' control, but in the sub control group 'address'

Comment: see [this almost similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652576/ngcontrol-with-ngfor-in-angular2), is this what you want ?

Comment: @A_Singh, Yes it's something like that

Comment: than, you just need to do what [Günter suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35652723/5612697). Apart from `array of controls` you can also use `addControl` and `removeControl` on `controlGroup` if you like.

Comment: I try, it didn't work. You can take a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/ffYe1479WnxYOQrbxwLF?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I implemented it for you, see [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vBfOtOi4l2ytfTNyrg6o?p=preview) or better yet, [Plunker -@waldo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ffYe1479WnxYOQrbxwLF?p=preview)

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {
  FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, ControlArray, Validators, NgForm, Control,
  AbstractControl
} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [ngFormModel]="userForm" *ngIf="userForm">
      <p><label><input id="date" type="text" ngControl="name" #name="ngForm"/> Name</label></p>

      <p><label><input id="date" type="text" ngControl="firstName" #firstName="ngForm"/> FirstName</label></p>

      <h3>Add address</h3>
        <ul ngControlGroup="addresses">

        <li *ngFor="#ctrl of objToArray(userForm.find('addresses').controls); #i = index" 
        ngControlGroup="{{ctrl}}">
           {{ctrl}}:
          <input ngControl="street" placeholder="Street">
          <input ngControl="streetNumber"  placeholder="StreetNumber"> 
        </li>
      </ul>

    <div (click)="addAddress()" style="cursor: pointer"> Add Another Address</div>

    </form>

    `,
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
  userForm: ControlGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.userForm = fb.group({
      name: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
      firstName: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
      addresses: fb.group({
        address1: fb.group({
          street: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
          streetNumber: fb.control(null, Validators.required)
        })
      })
    });

    console.log(this.userForm);

  }

  objToArray(o){
    return Object.keys(o);
  }

  addAddress() {
    let addressField = this.fb.group({
      street: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
      streetNumber: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required)
    });

    (<ControlGroup>this.userForm.find('addresses')).addControl(
      'address' + (Object.keys((<ControlGroup>this.userForm.find('addresses')).controls).length + 1), addressField);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I've made some test by my side and finally find something like your code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ffYe1479WnxYOQrbxwLF?p=preview

Comment: Hi, can you guys please help me with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257443/onsubmit-return-all-the-rows-input-values-angular-2/38259063#38259063

Comment: Hi Waldo, when I try your method of adding another row, I get this error "[ts] 
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.". Any idea what I might be missing?