# How to dynamically add and remove form fields in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add input fields dynamically while the user clicks the add button and for each form field there must be a remove button, when the user clicks that the form fields must be removed, I need to achieve this using Angular 2, as I'm new to Angular 2 please help me to complete it

What I have tried

I have created a set of fields (3 select box and 1 text box), created a button called add fields, but I have tried it in angular 1.x its working fine but in angular 2 I don't know how to complete it, this is [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8rZyS06ByBfH4IOIVo2T?p=preview) of my full work

```
app/app.component.ts
 import {
    Component
  }
from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-success bt-sm">add</button>
    <form role="form" calss="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
    <label>Select State:</label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rules.State" id="sel1">
            <option>State1</option>
            <option>State2</option>
            <option>State3</option>
            <option>State4</option>
</select>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
<label>Rule:</label>
     <input type="text" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="form-                   control">
    </div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
<label>Pass State :</label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rules.pass">
    <option>State1</option>
    <option>State2</option>
    <option>State3</option>
    <option>State4</option>
</select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
    <label>Fail State:</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rules.fail">
        <option>State1</option>
        <option>State2</option>
        <option>State3</option>
     <option>State4</option>
     </select>
         </div>
    </form>
     </div>
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Rules Configuration</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                 <p>Rules</p>
                </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
             </div>

                </div>
                 </div>
`
    })
    export class AppComponent {
            title = 'Rule Engine Demo';
          rules: Rules = {
                  State: '',
                  pass: '',
                 fail: ''
                };
```

Comment: You can use `ControlGroup` to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627573/angular2-form-controlgroup-who-hold-an-undefined-number-of-control/36641967#36641967

Comment: @A_Singh do you have any idea why angular 2 in not loading the template html internal script codes

Comment: do you mean injecting scripts using `[innerHTML]` doesn't work ? It's because angular doesn't allow scripts to be injected that way

Comment: no the script tags, you have used jquery query builder ever ?..

Comment: `query builder` ? No. but it's happening also because angular doesn't allow any scripts in templates. see [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903)

Comment: then where I can load the script tags, if I load in index.html am getting a error as undefined type, if I need to use the script inside the template any idea u have

Answer (score 158, accepted):

This is a few months late but I thought I'd provide my solution based on [this here tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2). The gist of it is that it's a lot easier to manage once you change the way you approach forms.

First, use `ReactiveFormsModule` instead of or in addition to the normal `FormsModule`. With reactive forms you create your forms in your components/services and then plug them into your page instead of your page generating the form itself. It's a bit more code but it's a lot more testable, a lot more flexible, and as far as I can tell the best way to make a lot of non-trivial forms.

The end result will look a little like this, conceptually:

- You have one base `FormGroup` with whatever `FormControl` instances you need for the entirety of the form. For example, as in the tutorial I linked to, lets say you want a form where a user can input their name once and then any number of addresses. All of the one-time field inputs would be in this base form group.
- Inside that `FormGroup` instance there will be one or more `FormArray` instances. A `FormArray` is basically a way to group multiple controls together and iterate over them. You can also put multiple `FormGroup` instances in your array and use those as essentially "mini-forms" nested within your larger form.
- By nesting multiple `FormGroup` and/or `FormControl` instances within a dynamic `FormArray`, you can control validity and manage the form as one, big, reactive piece made up of several dynamic parts. For example, if you want to check if every single input is valid before allowing the user to submit, the validity of one sub-form will "bubble up" to the top-level form and the entire form becomes invalid, making it easy to manage dynamic inputs.
- As a `FormArray` is, essentially, a wrapper around an array interface but for form pieces, you can push, pop, insert, and remove controls at any time without recreating the form or doing complex interactions.

In case the tutorial I linked to goes down, here some sample code you can implement yourself (my examples use TypeScript) that illustrate the basic ideas:

**Base Component code:**

```ts
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-component',
  templateUrl: './my-form.component.html'
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() inputArray: ArrayType[];
    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
    ngOnInit(): void {
        let newForm = this.fb.group({
            appearsOnce: ['InitialValue', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(25)]],
            formArray: this.fb.array([])
        });

        const arrayControl = <FormArray>newForm.controls['formArray'];
        this.inputArray.forEach(item => {
            let newGroup = this.fb.group({
                itemPropertyOne: ['InitialValue', [Validators.required]],
                itemPropertyTwo: ['InitialValue', [Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(20)]]
            });
            arrayControl.push(newGroup);
        });

        this.myForm = newForm;
    }
    addInput(): void {
        const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['formArray'];
        let newGroup = this.fb.group({

            /* Fill this in identically to the one in ngOnInit */

        });
        arrayControl.push(newGroup);
    }
    delInput(index: number): void {
        const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['formArray'];
        arrayControl.removeAt(index);
    }
    onSubmit(): void {
        console.log(this.myForm.value);
        // Your form value is outputted as a JavaScript object.
        // Parse it as JSON or take the values necessary to use as you like
    }
}
```

**Sub-Component Code**: (one for each new input field, to keep things clean)

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-form-sub-component',
    templateUrl: './my-form-sub-component.html'
})
export class MyFormSubComponent {
    @Input() myForm: FormGroup; // This component is passed a FormGroup from the base component template
}
```

**Base Component HTML**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <label>Appears Once:</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="appearsOnce" />

    <div formArrayName="formArray">
        <div *ngFor="let control of myForm.controls['formArray'].controls; let i = index">
            <button type="button" (click)="delInput(i)">Delete</button>
            <my-form-sub-component [myForm]="myForm.controls.formArray.controls[i]"></my-form-sub-component>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addInput()">Add</button>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Sub-Component HTML**

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <label>Property One: </label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="propertyOne"/>

    <label >Property Two: </label>
    <input type="number" formControlName="propertyTwo"/>
</div>
```

In the above code I basically have a component that represents the base of the form and then each sub-component manages its own `FormGroup` instance within the `FormArray` situated inside the base `FormGroup`. The base template passes along the sub-group to the sub-component and then you can handle validation for the entire form dynamically.

Also, this makes it trivial to re-order component by strategically inserting and removing them from the form. It works with (seemingly) any number of inputs as they don't conflict with names (a big downside of template-driven forms as far as I'm aware) and you still retain pretty much automatic validation. The only "downside" of this approach is, besides writing a little more code, you do have to relearn how forms work. However, this will open up possibilities for much larger and more dynamic forms as you go on.

If you have any questions or want to point out some errors, go ahead. I just typed up the above code based on something I did myself this past week with the names changed and other misc. properties left out, but it should be straightforward. The only major difference between the above code and my own is that I moved all of the form-building to a separate service that's called from the component so it's a bit less messy.

Comment: How implement ngModel to that form ?

Comment: @elporfirio You don't use ngModel with these forms. ngModel is used mostly when dealing with two-way data binding with a JavaScript object. These reactive forms are essentially their own objects with various helpful fields and properties such as validation. Instead, you get the ".value" property from the form and that is the set of your results. You can manipulate that however you'd like and map it to any classes or interfaces you have.

Comment: yes above approch is very it's works for me , but i am not getting how to apply custom directive to above thing

Comment: You saved my date

Comment: @Faradox : You mean "day" isn't it ? ;)

Comment: I'm getting a 'Cannot find name ArrayType' compile error, under Angular8. Is this being pulled in by an import that's not listed?

Comment: In case the link dies: https://web.archive.org/web/20200205021421/https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

add and remove text input element dynamically any one can use this this will work  
                
                  
                    
                      
                        Type of Contact
                        
                          Balance Fund
                          Equity Fund
                         
                      
                      
                        Allocation
                        
                        
                            Allocation % is required! 
                      
                      
                         Remove 
                      
                    
                  
                
              
               Add Contact

```
userForm: FormGroup;
  public contactList: FormArray;
  // returns all form groups under contacts
  get contactFormGroup() {
    return this.userForm.get('funds') as FormArray;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.submitUser();
  }
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder,private router: Router,private ngZone: NgZone,private userApi: ApiService) { }
  // contact formgroup
  createContact(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      fundName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])], // i.e Email, Phone
      allocation: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
  }


  // triggered to change validation of value field type
  changedFieldType(index) {
    let validators = null;

    validators = Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(new RegExp('^\\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\\d[0-9]{9})$')) // pattern for validating international phone number
    ]);

    this.getContactsFormGroup(index).controls['allocation'].setValidators(
      validators
    );

    this.getContactsFormGroup(index).controls['allocation'].updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  // get the formgroup under contacts form array
  getContactsFormGroup(index): FormGroup {
    // this.contactList = this.form.get('contacts') as FormArray;
    const formGroup = this.contactList.controls[index] as FormGroup;
    return formGroup;
  }

  submitUser() {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      first_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      last_name: [''],
      email: ['', [Validators.required]],
      company_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      license_start_date: ['', [Validators.required]],
      license_end_date: ['', [Validators.required]],
      gender: ['Male'],
      funds: this.fb.array([this.createContact()])
    })
    this.contactList = this.userForm.get('funds') as FormArray;
  }
  addContact() {
    this.contactList.push(this.createContact());
  }
  removeContact(index) {
    this.contactList.removeAt(index);
  }
```

Comment: Not sure why you've posted two answers rather than one complete answer.  In order to make your answer as useful as possible, could you please ensure that you've got one answer with a good explanation as to how your answer adds value over the answer given accepted in 2016?

Comment: Please use "edit" button under the post to update it. Don't post your answer in two separate posts

Answer (score -1):

That is the HTML code. Anyone can use this:

```
<div class="card-header">Contact Information</div>
          <div class="card-body" formArrayName="funds">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6" *ngFor="let contact of contactFormGroup.controls; let i = index;">
                <div [formGroupName]="i" class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-6">
                    <label>Type of Contact</label>
                    <select class="form-control" formControlName="fundName" type="text">
                      <option value="01">Balance Fund</option>
                      <option value="02">Equity Fund</option>
                    </select> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-12">
                    <label>Allocation</label>
                    <input class="form-control" formControlName="allocation" type="number">
                    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="getContactsFormGroup(i).controls['allocation'].touched && 
                    getContactsFormGroup(i).controls['allocation'].hasError('required')">
                        Allocation % is required! </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-12 text-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="removeContact(i)"> Remove </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary m-1" type="button" (click)="addContact()"> Add Contact </button>
```

Answer (score -2):

addAccordian(type, data) {
    console.log(type, data);

```
let form = this.form;

if (!form.controls[type]) {
  let ownerAccordian = new FormArray([]);
  const group = new FormGroup({});
  ownerAccordian.push(
    this.applicationService.createControlWithGroup(data, group)
  );
  form.controls[type] = ownerAccordian;
} else {
  const group = new FormGroup({});
  (<FormArray>form.get(type)).push(
    this.applicationService.createControlWithGroup(data, group)
  );
}
console.log(this.form);
```

}