# Angular 2 Reactive forms - Create input fields dynamically

Tags: angular

Using Dynamic forms, I need to give users the ability to create forms fields dynamically. There needs to be a 'Add' button and when user clicks on this button, 4 input fields would be created.

I am able to create one field dynamically so far. Below is my code

In the HTML, I am using index to create the formControlName

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div formArrayName="properties">

              <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" (click)="onAddProperty()">Add</button>
              <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let propertyControl of searchForm.get('properties').controls; let i = index">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">

                <!--       <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="'B'"+"i">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="'C'"+"i">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="'D'"+"i"> -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and then in the component, pushing the control to the FormArray

```
searchForm: FormGroup;
onAddProperty() {
    const control = new FormControl(null);
    (<FormArray>this.searchForm.get('properties')).push(control);
  }
```

Now, I can click 'Add' button any number of times, and for every click one input field will be created.

However, instead of one input field, I need 4 inputs fields to be created for every click. I am not able to make out how to give each of these form fields unique formControlName. Right now, I am using index of the field which would be unique for 1 field, but wouldn't be so for 4 fields.

Comment: refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007236/how-to-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-fields-in-angular-2

Comment: create a loop??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think a simple `for` loop would do here. As for your template, I had some trouble understanding the code inside the comment (in template). In this case you don't need to do anything else than just declare the `formControlName`'s with index inside your iteration of formArray, so something like this:

```html
<div formArrayName="properties">
  <div *ngFor="let prop of searchForm.get('properties').controls; let i=index">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
</div>
```

And then the loop that inserts 4 new input fields:

```ts
onAddProperty() {
  for(var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    <FormArray>this.searchForm.get('properties').push(new FormControl());
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7vF2kin64iCgLDkmiaLU?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you very much. What if one of these 4 fields need to be a drop down?

Comment: Well, this is so little information to go on. What would be the content for the dropdown? And how to determine which one should be the dropdown? :)

Comment: Let's say the second field (of 4 fields) will always be a dropdown. It would just have 2 static values - 'Apples' and 'Oranges'

Comment: Okay, let me think for a while, I'll get back to you with something, either I'm so stupid that I can't figure this one out, or then I'm extremely smart! :D :D I'll get back to you :)

Comment: @kayasa, I couldn't really think of anything else, than building nested formgroups to the formarray. Hopefully this solution would work for you, even though it requires a bit more code and the form object is diffferent than before: http://plnkr.co/edit/HN8EO0WB0YsdIHFTC00f?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

did you see check this link [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YC2bZJ1MhE8jWIiXylsi?p=preview)

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="users">
      <div formArrayName="data">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let user of fData.controls; index as i">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <label>
              <span>Full name</span>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
            </label>
            <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('name').touched && user.get('name').hasError('required')">
              Name is required
            </div>
            <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('name').touched && user.get('name').hasError('minlength')">
              Minimum of 2 characters
            </div>
            <div formGroupName="account">
              <label>
                <span>Email address</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
              </label>
              <div
                class="error"
                *ngIf="user.get('account').get('email').hasError('required') && user.get('account').get('email').touched">
                Email is required
              </div>
              <label>
                <span>Confirm address</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Address" formControlName="confirm">
              </label>
              <div
                class="error"
                *ngIf="user.get('account').get('confirm').hasError('required') && user.get('account').get('confirm').touched">
                Confirming email is required
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="user.invalid">Sign up</button>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </form>
```