# How to add dynamic validation with reative forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I want to add validation on dynamically generated field. This is my code.

```
projectForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer,private router: Router,private fb: FormBuilder,private projectService: ProjectService,private fnService:FunctionsService, private  userService : UserService) {      

    this.projectForm = fb.group({
        'shirnkrap':[null, Validators.required],
        'cd_text':[null, Validators.required],
        'assignto':[null, Validators.required],
        'projecttype':[null, Validators.required]

    });
}
```

on one function i want to add new validation which will trigger on `<select>`change event.

I try this,

`this.projectForm.controls['project_name'].setValidators([Validators.required]);`
but it give me this error,

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValidators' of undefined`

So can someone help me how can i add validation?

Comment: there is no control called project_name

Comment: control will created dynamically, on change event

Comment: How have you add this control? There might be the issue

Comment: Can you share your code for adding the control?  It should be something like : let control = new FormControl();
 this.projectForm.addControl('project_name', control);

Comment: With your code simply inside a comment, it's really difficult to understand why the FormControl you added is undefined when you try to add a validator on it. Please update your answer with the relevant pieces of code needed to understand your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not exactly with adding a validator to your form. It's more adding a control dynamically to your form.

Unfortunately, it looks like it's not something that is feasible with the method `addControl`. As per [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#how-to-use), you should only use `addControl()` when you are instantiating the form.

So, how to deal with dynamic controls? 2 things are feasible: the first one, that looks too complicated would be to use a `FormArray`. Have a look at this answer for more information : [How to dynamically add and remove form fields in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007236/how-to-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-fields-in-angular-2)

The second one would be to initialize your form directly with your dynamic field:

```
this.projectForm = fb.group({
    'shirnkrap':[null, Validators.required],
    'cd_text':[null, Validators.required],
    'assignto':[null, Validators.required],
    'projecttype':[null, Validators.required],
    'project_name': ''
});
```

Inside your template, you would only have to hide that field based on your condition (using `ng-if="my-selected-value === 'someValue'"`

Then, on your `<select>` change, you would have to add your validator :

```
if(my-selected-value === 'someValue') {
    this.myForm.controls["firstName"].setValidators([Validators.required]);
    this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Do not forget to update the validity of your form. Otherwise you will have to wait for the user to update a field before seeing that your form is not valid anymore.

You can see an example on Deborah Kurata's tutorial on Reactive Form here:

- [Template with `*ngIf`](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms/blob/master/Demo-Final-Updated/src/app/customers/customer.component.html#L176)
- [Form is directly built with adresses](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms/blob/master/Demo-Final-Updated/src/app/customers/customer.component.ts#L63)
- [The way she suggests to update validators](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms/blob/master/Demo-Final-Updated/src/app/customers/customer.component.ts#L109) (on another field)

Comment: Thanks for such descriptive answer, this give me proper idea how to solve my problem.

Answer (score -3):

Use following code to add validation dynamically:

```
this.myForm.controls["firstName"].setValidators([Validators.required]);
```

Your formGroup object don't have project_name field. You can also add formcontrol dynamically in your formgroup object.

```
this.projectForm.addControl("project_name", new FormControl(null));
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Exactly what OP tried! `this.projectForm.controls['project_name'].setValidators([Validators.required]);`. Furthermore, it's incomplete!

Comment: That's still what OP has asked.