# ng-invalid class been applied to formArrayName container

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I followed this [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007236/how-to-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-fields-in-angular-2/), but I am facing an issue. I am using `css` to make the color of the form control to red when it is invalid.

```
.ng-invalid:not(form) {
    border:  1px solid red;
}
```

This is the css provided by angular and after this when i run in production mode, see that this css is applied to whole formArray and red box appears for all.

This is how it looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormArray` will also be `invalid` when any item of it is invalid. Your css just excludes `form` but not `formArrayName` element.

Try with below example

```
// excluding form and any elements with formarrayname attribute
.ng-invalid:not(form):not([formarrayname]) {
  border:  1px solid red;
}
```

If you bind to `formArrayName` via variable, the `formarrayname` will not be setted to `div`, so you will need to exclude `div` instead.

```
// excluding form and div with ng-invalid
.ng-invalid:not(form):not(div) {
  border:  1px solid red;
}
```

Refer **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsbrc8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)** and **[dynamic binding demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bq26xk?file=src/app/app.component.css)**.

Comment: i am still getting the same, are you sure with the spelling for **formarrayname**

Comment: @YashSharma See my updated answer. There is link which leads to the demo.

Comment: <div formArrayName="testArr"> my form is dynamic and require <div [formArrayName]="category.categoryID"> and not working for me but in your case it works

Comment: @YashSharma I have reproduced you error. For your case, `formarrayname` attribute is not reflected on `div`. You can try by `not(div)`. See my updated answer.