# How to get the values of multiple checkboxes in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I am trying to get the values of the checkboxes that are selected. I have the following code:

```
<div style="background-color:lightblue;" >
    <div class="content">
       <label class="label">Province</label>
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline" *ngFor = "let province of utilities.Provinces; let i of index">    
           <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" >{{province}}</label>
           <input class="form-check-input" [formControl]= "province" (change)="getSelectedProvinces()" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox{{i}}" value="option1"> 
      </div>
 </div>
```

In .ts I have the following

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UtilitiesService } from '../_services/utilities.service';
import { Utilities } from '../models/utilities';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

@Component({
selector: 'app-filtering',
templateUrl: './filtering.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./filtering.component.css']
})
export class FilteringComponent implements OnInit {
   utilities: Utilities;
   provinces:  string[] = [];
   selectedProvinces: string[] = [];
   selectedCategories: string[] = [];

   constructor(private utilityService: UtilitiesService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.loadUtilities();
  }

  loadUtilities() {
    this.utilityService.getJSON().subscribe((utilities: Utilities) => {
    this.utilities = utilities;
    });

    for (const  province of this.utilities.Provinces) {
      this.provinces.push(province);
    }
  }

  getSelectedProvinces() {
      this.selectedProvinces = [];
      this.utilities.Provinces.forEach((_province, i) => {
          if (_province.value) {
          this.selectedProvinces.push(this.provinces[i]);
      }
  });
 console.log(this.selectedProvinces);
}

}
```

In my `utilities.ts` I have the following:

```
export interface Utilities {
  Provinces: Array<string>;
}
```

My service is written as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Utilities } from '../models/utilities';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UtilitiesService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

public getJSON(): Observable<Utilities> {
   return this.http.get<Utilities>('./assets/utilities.json');
}

}
```

The Json that is has the following content:

```
{
   "Provinces":["East","North West","North"]
}
```

When I try that, I have the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Provinces' of undefined.
```

The thing is, when I remove `[formControl]= "province" (change)="getSelectedProvinces()"`, at least I am able to display the provinces on my page.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically add and remove form fields in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007236/how-to-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-fields-in-angular-2)

Comment: I think you should be mapping your api response to Observable<Provinces[]> instead of Utilities and use that. The naming is also misleading in case of Utilities. Usually anything named in plural form should refer to a collection, not a single object

Comment: @ihorbond, the problem is that I may have to add more properties to that JSON

Comment: Hey I solve this with cdk selectionmodel: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/drevrrgpaqx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-selection-example.ts); [material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem using this code below:

```
<div class="content">
<label class="label">Province</label>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline" *ngFor="let province of utilities.Provinces">    
    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{province}}">{{province}}</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" (change)="onChangeCategory(province, $event.target.checked)"name="{{ province}}" type="checkbox" id="{{province}}"> 
</div>
```

In my `.ts`, I have the following:

```
onChangeProvince(province: string, isChecked: boolean) {
   if (isChecked) {
         this.selectedProvinces.push(province);
   } else {
       const index = this.selectedProvinces.indexOf(province);
       this.selectedProvinces.splice(index, 1);
   }

 console.log(this.selectedProvinces);

}
```