# angular2 dynamic form with *ngFor, two-way-binding [(ngModel)] and form validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

### Problem Statement

I am trying to create a dynamic form where parts of the interface responds to updates of the model:

- user clicks on a button
- new model entity is added to the components internal list and a **new control group** (with multiple child controls, each with dedicated validators) is created and attached to the form.
- each of this child controls should establish a two-way-binding which its corresponding entry in the model [(ngModel)] and propagate state up to the top-level form

### Where I am Stuck

My current problem is that i do not know how to reference a **new control group** (stored in an ControlArray) from within the template.

All dynamic form solutions I found so far worked without a backing model and two-way-databinding.

- [Angular2 form ControlGroup who hold an undefined number of Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627573/angular2-form-controlgroup-who-hold-an-undefined-number-of-control) (and the mentioned plunkr)
- [ngControl with ngFor in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652576/ngcontrol-with-ngfor-in-angular2)

### Code

I have created a plunkr for below code: https://plnkr.co/edit/nP6hcIXKA0jz2F8Epg2L?p=preview

My (simplyfied) data model:

```
class Entry {
    constructor(
        public _id: string,
        public _title: string
    ) {}
}

class Data {
    constructor(
        public heading: string,
        public entries: Entry[] = []
    ) {}
}
```

My template:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Dynamic Form</h1>
        <form [ngFormModel]="formModel">
            <label>heading: </label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="heading" [ngFormControl]="formModel.controls.heading">
            <div>
                <hr>
                <!-- PROBLEM: how to get a reference to a single Control from within ControlGroup from within formModel.controls['entries'] that can be wired with belows <input> fields? -->
                <div *ngFor="#entry of data.entries; #i = index">
                    <label>id: </label>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="entry._id" #ctrlId="ngForm"> <span><b>is valid: </b>{{ctrlId.control.valid}}</span>
                    <br>
                    <label>title: </label>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="entry._title" #ctrlTitle="ngForm"><span><b>is valid: </b>{{ctrlTitle.control.valid}}</span>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <input type="button" (click)="add()" value="add new entry">
        <div>{{ctrlCount}}</div>
        <div>{{debug}}</div>
        <div>{{debugForm}}</div>
    `
})
```

My Component:

```
export class DynamicForm implements OnInit {
    data:Data;

    formModel:ControlGroup;

    constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
        this.formModel = fb.group({
            heading: fb.control('test heading', Validators.required),
            entries: fb.array([])
        })
    }

    ngOnInit():void {
        /* init the heading */
        this.data = new Data('test heading');

        /* init the entries > add to model, create control and add it to ControlArray */
        [
            new Entry('1', 'one'),
            new Entry('2', 'two'),
            new Entry('3', 'three'),
            new Entry('4', 'four'),
        ].forEach((e:Entry) => this.add(e));
    }

    add(e:Entry):void {
        let id:string = e ? e._id : '';
        let title:string = e ? e._title : '';

        (<ControlArray>this.formModel.controls['entries']).push(this.fb.group({
            id: this.fb.control(id, Validators.required),
            title: this.fb.control(title, Validators.required),
        }));
        this.data.entries.push(new Entry(id, title));
    }

    get debug() {
        return JSON.stringify({debug_data: this.data});
    }

    get debugForm() {
        return JSON.stringify({
            debug_form: {
                dirty: this.formModel.dirty,
                pristine: this.formModel.pristine,
                touched: this.formModel.touched,
                untouched: this.formModel.untouched,
                valid: this.formModel.valid,
            }
        });
    }

    get ctrlCount() {
        return (<ControlArray>this.formModel.controls['entries']).length;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `formModel.controls['entries']` not do that you want to do? How are `ControlGroup`s related to your question. I don't see you using them?

Comment: It actually does, but i just noticed i got syntax wrong. I tried to grab the controls using array index like this

`
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="entry._id" [ngFormControl]="formModel.controls['entries'][i].find('id')" #ctrlId="ngForm">
`

instead of using `ObjectArrays` dedicated `.at()` method:

`\`

Comment: this works: `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="entry._title" [ngFormControl]="formModel.controls['entries'].at(i).find('title')" #ctrlTitle="ngForm">`

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Description of `ControlArray.at()`: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/ControlArray-class.html#!#at-anchor