# Add multiple ngControls with ngFor

Tags: angular, dart, angular2-forms

Is any proper way to generate `*ngControl`s with `*ngFor` with template based approach? The problem is same as in [ngControl with ngFor in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652576/ngcontrol-with-ngfor-in-angular2), but don't want to obstruct controller logic with controls generation. In angular beta 17 was working

```
<form>
    <input *ngFor="let val of vals; let idx = index" [ngModel]="val" ngControl="input-{{idx}}">
</form>
```

but in 2.0.0 updating `vals` with this approach causes `EXCEPTION: The null object does not have a method 'updateValue'`.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
... ngControl="'input' + idx" ...
```

or

```
ngControl="input{{idx}}
```

Comment: Both options are the same as mine, except for the name of control, which does not affect the problem at all.